# FormBuilder Control causing "Expression has changed after it was checked" exception

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-forms

I have a form that is being instantiated programatically via `DynamicComponentLoader::loadIntoLocation`. The form code is below:

```
constructor (
    private _builder: FormBuilder
) {
    this.editForm = _builder.group({
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Helpers.emailValidator])],
        phone: [''],
        phoneAlt: [''],
        location: [''],
        dob: [''],
        bio: [''],
    });
}
```

You'll notice that some of the forms don't have validators (as far as I can tell, this is the same as using `Validators.nullValidator`, I've tested with both).

In my template I have the following code (for each control):

```
<label for="phone">Contact Number <span *ngIf="!phone.valid">- {{e(phone)}}</span></label>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" ngControl="phone" #phone="ngForm">
```

The first control that doesn't have a validator throws the following exception twice when it hits the `!phone.valid` part of the template:

```
EXCEPTION: Expression '!phone.valid in e@15:43' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false' in [!phone.valid in e@15:43]
```

At no point am I touching the controls or `this.editForm` after the initial creation, so, as far as my code is concerned, nothing should be changing.

I'm aware that I can suppress the errors by calling `enableProdMode()` but I'd rather fix the problem than hide it.

**Edit (8th Feb):** I have since tried moving the contents of the modal to a separate page, but the errors persist. This would suggest the issue is not related to the way I am creating and loading the modals, but rather the ControlGroup or FormBuilder.

**[Plunker of the issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/YBU0TRyGI4uMx2HCosqB?p=preview)** | [Plunker without modal](http://plnkr.co/edit/KkgSU3I44CZGujsrfbE9?p=preview)

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6041

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to [qdouble](https://github.com/qdouble) for solving this for me on the [Angular Gitter](https://gitter.im/angular/angular?at=56b8d0a9939ffd5d15f677d0) chat.

The issue seemed to be caused by the order in which angular parsed the page. By going from top to bottom, `ngIf="!phone.valid"` was being parsed before `phone.valid` had been initialised. This was easily fixed by adding a catch in the if statement to make sure that it was not null `*ngIf="phone.valid === null ? false : !phone.valid"` (or by moving the label after the input).

Comment: Thanks, this still works perfect :)

Answer (score 9):

This was the problem I ran into.

Angular 2 introduced a feature to better handle change detection.  Angular 2 drops the digest cycles in favor of one-way flow which is about 3-10 times faster and handles asynchronous logic better.

```
@Component({
    ...
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})...
```

**Links:**
Angular Reference: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectionStrategy-enum.html

Understanding change detection: https://auth0.com/blog/understanding-angular-2-change-detection/

How Angular 2 Change Detection Really Works: http://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Comment: This can be dangerous because it concretely disables the change detection which is activated only in dev and usefull to know other problems: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/

Answer (score 3):

using ngAfterContentChecked fixed the error in my side

```
ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: You can also add it after a function which alters code asynchronously - in my case it was right after `this.control.setAsyncValidators(...)`. This forced another render of the view and the problem disappeared.

Comment: I have the same issue with setAsyncValidators... There is no other way to use it in a ngOnInit ?

Comment: could you please create a quick reproduction demo and pass the link here, it's easier for me to help you :)